# How to get the downloadable products link collection order by title

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I am struggling from last two hours to get the all downloadable product links order by title, but not able to achieve because it's giving the wrong order by collection.

Can anyone help me :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the all downloadable collection by

```
$products = Mage::getModel('downloadable/link')->getCollection();
```

but when you try to add the title in this collection using

```
$products->->addTitleToResult();
```

then this will automatically add two sorting order one by sort_order ASC and second one by title ASC. So that you will never get the actual sorting result because sort_order always come first. For more details see

`Mage_Downloadable_Model_Resource_Link_Collection::addTitleToResult()`

So you need to override the above class in your local pool and need to remove

`->order('main_table.sort_order ASC'` from `addTitleToResult()`

or create a custom class for the same.